# class androidx.appcompat.widget.AlertDialogLayout not found exception

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have this strange problem, im getting this exception

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: androidx.appcompat.widget.AlertDialogLayout
java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
java.lang.Class.forName Class.java:454
android.view.LayoutInflater.createView LayoutInflater.java:815
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag LayoutInflater.java:1006
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag LayoutInflater.java:961
androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555
androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDialog.setContentView AppCompatDialog.java:95
androidx.appcompat.app.AlertController.installContent AlertController.java:232
androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog.onCreate AlertDialog.java:279
android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate Dialog.java:554
mono.android.view.View_OnClickListenerImplementor.onClick View_OnClickListenerImplementor.java:30
android.view.View.performClick View.java:7870
mono.android.view.View_OnClickListenerImplementor.onClick View_OnClickListenerImplementor.java:30
android.view.View.performClick View.java:7870
```

when i try to show a simple diallog in Xamarin.android.
i have in "skip linking assemplies" list this androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;

and also i have add this class

```
using Android.App;
using AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget;

namespace RateMe
{
    static class LinkerPleaseInclude
    {
        static bool falseflag = false;
        static LinkerPleaseInclude()
        {
            if (falseflag)
            {
                var ignore = new FitWindowsLinearLayout(Application.Context);
                var ignore1 = new FitWindowsFrameLayout(Application.Context);
                var ignore2 = new AlertDialogLayout(Application.Context);
                var ignore3 = new AndroidX.AppCompat.App.AlertDialog(Application.Context);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

im using this class to define my AlertDialog

using AlertDialog = AndroidX.AppCompat.App.AlertDialog;

but i keep getting this exception, only on release configuration (linking sdk and user assemblies i have choose), what i have to do?

Comment: `androidx.appcompat` is what you actually should add in the link skip!

Comment: I will try it but do you know why i have to exclude it in the first place? Is because of the using im doing? Should i include something else?

Comment: I tried your suggestion also and now im getting exception that androidx.appcombat.widget.alertdialogtitle not found